# getting segfault in a group of related projects

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am getting segfaults on several  projects rgbdtam rgbdslam_v2,  lsd_slam
I get either a sexit  code 11 or if I run as rosrun the just the line segfault.
How can I investigate these errors further...they seem to be related to a group that may be dependent on pcl or such.
I am running ubuntu16.
How can I investigate and localize the responsible subsystem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274434/getting-segfault-in-a-group-of-related-projects/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2017-10-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

this can be done by using

make sure you do not specify the cwd argument as this will prevent gdb from finding the executable.

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2017-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0